# Single or Multiple MySqlDataReaders

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have two databases, one is local and the other one is remote. I can leech data with MySqlDataReader from local, but can't get from remote even if I did a succesfull connection. I tried to create another MySqlDataReader object but failed again. Here is my code:

```
        using(MySqlCommand cmd2 = connL.CreateCommand())
        {
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {

                cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT userid FROM users";

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                    dr.Read();
                    string userid = dr[i].ToString();
                    dr.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show(userid);
                    //here, I can see the id

                    MySqlCommand cmd3 = connR.CreateCommand();
                    cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd3.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = \"" + userid + "\"";
                    dr = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
                    dr.Read();

                    if (!dr[0].Equals("")) //! but in this line it says:
                    //Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(dr[0].ToString());
                    }
                        dr.Close();

                }



            }
        }
```

I couldn't find the solution for this error :(, by the way I am new with c#, sorry if it is a duplicate.

Comment: You should check the result of `Read()` like: `if (dr.Read()){}` And take a look a parameterized queries and `using`statements.

Comment: I tried to check it like this:
        if (dr.Read())
                        {

                            MessageBox.Show((dr == null).ToString());
                        }

but it says out of bounds :(

Comment: Why are doing `dr==null`?

Comment: because I tought indexoutofrange exception came from dr[0]==null or "" then change it into dr==null :D

Comment: Please check with the debugger if your `dr` contains any data

Comment: thanks for the help! probably I have a logic error in somewhere, I will find it and if that would be about my main focus on this question I will update this question or delete, thank again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you actually checked if your DataReader contains any data?
The Out of bounds exception you're receiving indicates that you're trying to access an array that doesn't have the key you're asking for.

I've tested your code, and it works as it should. Try replacing this:

```
cmd3.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = \"" + userid + "\"";
```

with this:

```
cmd3.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users";
```

Just to see if you're receiving any data.

You could also use a while around your DataReader.Read to prevent any out of bounds exceptions.

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    MessageBox.Show(dr.ToString());
}
```

Comment: thanks for help, I found my problem, its about my looking at wrong data array.